# Is there an R function that assigns value if the date is in between two other dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, join

I have two datasets, one dataset is a calendar translation. Meaning, that there are encoded weeks, e.g:

| Week | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `2678` | 2011-06-18 | 2011-06-24 |
| `3689` | 2011-06-25 | 2011-07-01 |
| `8976` | 2011-07-02 | 2011-07-08 |

All dates have "Date" format, "%Y-%m-%d".

Then, I have a dataset with temperatures.
The dataset looks like:

| Date | Temperature min | Temperature max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `2011-06-19` | 14 | 23 |
| `2011-06-20` | 20 | 26 |
| `2011-06-21` | 15 | 18 |

I want to combine the datasets, and join it this way that I have following result:

| Date | Temperature min | Temperature max | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `2011-06-19` | 14 | 23 | 2678 |
| `2011-06-20` | 20 | 26 | 2678 |
| `2011-06-21` | 15 | 18 | 2678 |

I tried with if statements, however it did not work out. Is there a way to combine datasets this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `fuzzy_left_join` with the `match_fun` argument:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(df2, df1, by = c("Date" = "Start",
                                 "Date" = "End"),
                match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)
                ) %>% 
  select(-c(Start, End))
```

```
        Date Temperature_min Temperature_max Week
1 2011-06-19              14              23 2678
2 2011-06-20              20              26 2678
3 2011-06-21              15              18 2678
```